# Remove rows that contain more than one occurrence of a character (in any column)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to remove rows that contain more than one occurrence of a determined character in any column, but I'm not finding a way of doing that using pandas dataframe.
For example:

[image]

Would become:

[image]

Does anyone know a way to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: Would you mind posting some example data as code, not as image, with the expected input and output (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
>>> df[~df.eq('?').sum(axis=1).gt(1)]
   x  y  z
0  1  2  ?
1  3  2  1
3  2  3  1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for any duplicates including the numbers, you can try:

```
>>> df.loc[~df.T.apply(pd.Series.duplicated, keep=False).T.any(axis=1)]
   x  y  z
0  1  2  ?
1  3  2  1
3  2  3  1
```